# How do I have a pulsing animation on a circle drawn on a canvas

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas, android-custom-view

Is it possible to have a pulsing animation, like the sonar pulsation,  on a circle that I have drawn in a custom view canvas? For now I was able to have a second circle drawn at the same position and having its size changed using [ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator). 
[image]

All circles are bouncing slowly on the canvas. I want to have that animatioon be applied to "BOSS" circle. Right now, I have another circle drawn behind it that is haviing its size changed from 0 to BOOS circle's size + some values.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can do this with the help of ripple background. Check this link: https://github.com/huang125/RippleView

This is a ripple view library with animation in circle way. Use it as your needs

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Does it work with objects drawn on canvas?